# merging column in libreoffice calc does not work when drag down

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I'm merging columns in Libre Office using the `CONCATENATE` function.
I'm merging all text using:

```
CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1," ",C1," ",D1," ",E1," ",F1," ",G1)
```

According to [this suggestion](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/excel-2010-merge-cells-concatenation/), I should be able to apply the function over the whole column by dragging the plus sign; however, when I drag the plus sign, it only copies the first line, but I want to merge the next row.

How can I merge the columns correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@oczdref, I am not sure why this would not work in your situation. Here is what I did (please ignore the `;` separators, in your case they should remain `,`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also found out that you must enable the "AutoCalculate" under Tools -> Cell contents
so that when you drag the autocomplete function instead of getting the result
something like this:

[image]

and the result that i want to.

[image]